# Plotting Limit Cycle

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, parametric-functions

I have Lotka Volterra Equations where the prey equation is modified. The Equations are

```
x'[t]=a*x[t]*(1-x[t]/k)-b*x[t]*y[t]
y'[t]=-c*y[t]+d*x[t]*y[t]
```

To plot the limit cycles, i used `NDSolve` to solve the coupled nonlinear differential equations for x[t] and y[t]. I then used `ParametricPlot` to plot for `x[t]` and `y[t]` with respect to `t`, but I'm not getting appropriate limit cycles.

I did a steady state analysis of the equations and got certain conditions on the value of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `k`. The equation has a non-trivial steady state, at $(x,y)=(c/d,(a/b)-(ac/bdk))$. The commands are:

```
Equations = {x'[t] == a*x[t]*(1 - x[t]/k) - b*x[t]*y[t], x[0] == 2, y[0] == 1, y'[t] == -c*y[t] + d*x[t]*y[t]}; 
s = NDSolve[Equations, {x, y}, {t, 0, time}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 30}]
```

For the value of `a = 2; b = 1; c = 2.5; d = 1.2; k = 2.8`, I'm supposed to get a unstable spiral. But instead, the trajectory approaches the steady state of $(x,y) = (2.08333 , 0.511905)$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please give the values of the constants you have used, and also the `NDSolve` and `Plot`ting commands you used. Also, you say you don't get appropriate limit cycles, so what would you have expected instead of what you get?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer - I did a steady state analysis of the equations and got certain conditions on the value of a,b,c,d and k. Now, the equation has a non trivial steady state, at (x,y)=(c/d,(a/b)-(ac/bdk)).S
s
The commands are - Equations = {x'[t] == a*x[t]*(1 - x[t]/k) - b*x[t]*y[t], x[0] == 2, 
   y[0] == 1, y'[t] == -c*y[t] + d*x[t]*y[t]};
s = NDSolve[{Equations}, {x, y}, {t, 0, time}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 30}]

Comment: Thanks. Just to have a reasonable starting point, what values did you use for `a, b, c, d, k`? `NDSolve` will not do anything without specifying these.

Comment: For the value of a = 2; b = 1; c = 2.5; d = 1.2; k = 2.8,  I'm supposed to get a unstable spiral. But instead, the Parametric Plot goes to the steady state  of (x,y)=(2.08333 , 0.511905)

Comment: Please edit your question to include all necessary data; otherwise, people can't help you with your problem.

Answer (score 10):

**Hopf bifurcation analysis**

The differential system:

```
f1[x_,y_]:=a x (1 - x/k) - b x y; 
f2[x_,y_]:=-c y + d x y; 
F[{x_,y_},{a_,b_,c_,d_,k_}]:=Evaluate@{f1[x,y],f2[x,y]};
X={x, y};
μ={a,b,c,d,k};
```

$$
\begin{align}
 &\dot{x}=a x\left(1-\frac{x}{k} \right)- bxy\\
 &\dot{y}= dxy - cy
\end{align}
$$

The Jacobian matrix:

```
J[{x_,y_},{a_,b_,c_,d_,k_}]:=Evaluate@D[F[X,μ],{X}]
```

The non-trivial equilibrium point:

```
X0=Normal[Simplify[SolveValues[F[X,μ]==0&&Variables[F[X,μ]]>0,X]]][[1]];
MatrixForm@X0
```

$$
\begin{align}
 P_{0}(x,y)=\left(\frac{c}{d} ,\frac{a}{b}\left(1-\frac{c}{dk} \right)\right)
\end{align}
$$
The linear approximation at $P_{0}$ (coexistence equilibrium point):

```
J0=Simplify@J[X0,μ];
MatrixForm@J0
```

$$
\begin{align}
 J(P_{0})=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\hspace{-0.25cm}-\displaystyle\frac{a c}{d k} & -\displaystyle\frac{b c}{d}\hspace{0.3cm} \\\\
 \hspace{0.2cm}\displaystyle\frac{a (d k-c)}{b k} &\hspace{0.2cm} 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}
$$
Under the Hopf bifurcation conditions, $\text{tr}(J(P_{0},\mu_{0}))=0$ and $\text{det}(J(P_{0},\mu_{0}))>0$, where $\mu_{0}$ is the critical bifurcation value for some parameter of our system. In our case, the parameters are strictly positive and $\text{tr}(J(P_{0}))$ cannot be zero. Therefore, Hopf bifurcation not take place at $P_{0}$. The non-trivial equilibrium $P_{0}$ is always locally stable and the only condition that must be fulfilled is given by the following inequality
$$
\frac{c}{d k}<1
$$
Code for time series and phase portrait:

Time series

```
s = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] (1 - x[t]/k) - bx[t]*y[t], 
y'[t] == -c y[t] + d x[t]*y[t], x[0] == 11/5, y[0] == 4/5}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1000}, {a, b, c, d, k}];
Plot[Evaluate[x[1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 1/4, 10][t] /. s], {t, 0, 300}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 500, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.003]},AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Small], Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.95]]
```

[image: Time series]

Phase portrait:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 1/4, 10][t], y[1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 1/4, 10][t]} /. s], 
{t, 0, 300}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 500, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.003]}, 
AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Small],Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.95]]
```

[image: Phase portrait]

**Example: Hopf bifurcation in the Brusselator system**

`Calculation of the first Lyapunov coefficient`

The Brusselator system is given by:
$$
\begin{align}
 &\dot{x}=\alpha-(\beta+1)x + x^2 y\\
 &\dot{y}= \beta x - x^2 y
\end{align}
$$

Assuming $\alpha> 0$ fixed and taking $\beta$ as a bifurcation parameter, we show that at $\beta = 1 + \alpha^2$ the system exhibits a supercritical Hopf bifurcation.

The Brusselator system code:

```
f1[x_, y_] := α - (β + 1) x + x^2 y;
f2[x_, y_] := β x - x^2 y;
F[{x_, y_}, {α_, β_}] := Evaluate@{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]};
X = {x, y};
μ = {α, β};
U = {u, v};
R = {r, s};
```

The Jacobian matrix and its transpose:

```
J[{x_, y_}, {α_, β_}] = D[F[X, μ], {X}];
Jt[{x_, y_}, {α_, β_}] = Transpose[J[X, μ]];
MatrixForm[J[X, μ]]
MatrixForm[Jt[X, μ]]
```

Stability analysis (Routh-Hurwitz criterion):

```
X0[{α_, β_}] = SolveValues[F[X, μ] == 0, X][[1]]
polJX0 = Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[J[X0[μ], μ], λ], λ,Simplify];
a0 = CoefficientList[polJX0, λ][[3]];
a1 = CoefficientList[polJX0, λ][[2]];
a2 = CoefficientList[polJX0, λ][[1]];
Reduce[a1 > 0 && a2 > 0 && α > 0 && β > 0, β]
(*α > 0 && 0 < β < 1 + α^2*)
```

Note that $a_{1}=0$ if and only if  $β=β_{0}$, where $β_{0}=1+α^2$. Then, the Brusselator is locally asymptotically stable at $X_{0}(\mu)$ for $β<β_{0}$ and locally asymptotically unstable for $β>β_{0}$ (appears a stable limit cycle surrounded the unstable equilibrium point). We verify the previous conclusion (transversality condition) with the sign of the following derivative:

```
D[-a1, β]
(*1*)
```

The analysis at the critical bifurcation value $β_{0}$:

Solve the following system of equations:
$$
\left\{\begin{align}
F\left((x,y),(\alpha,\beta)\right) &=0, \\
\operatorname{tr}(J((x,y),(\alpha,\beta))) &=0,
\end{align}\right.
$$
for $(x,y,\beta)$ and we must check that det $\operatorname{det}J((x,y),(\alpha,\beta))>0$ when $\beta = \beta_{0}$ for the solution found, where $\beta_{0}$ is the Hopf critical bifurcation value.

The code for the above system of equations:

```
X0μ0 = Delete[Part[SolveValues[F[X, μ] == 0 && Tr[J[X, μ]] == 0, {x, y, β}], 1], {3}]
μ0 = Prepend[Delete[Part[SolveValues[F[X, μ] == 0 && Tr[J[X, μ]] == 0, {x, y, β}], 1], {{1}, {2}}], α]
Det[J[X0μ0, μ0]]
```

Here, the Hopf critical bifurcation value is $\beta_{0}=1+\alpha^2$ and $\operatorname{det}J((x,y),(\alpha,\beta_{0}))=\alpha^2>0$. Thus, the Brusselator at $\beta_{0}=1+\alpha^2$ has the equilibrium
$$
\begin{align}
X_{0}(\mu_{0})=\left(\alpha, \displaystyle\frac{1+\alpha^2}{\alpha} \right)
\end{align}
$$
and the linear approximation at $X_{0}(\mu_{0})$ has purely imaginary eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm \omega i$, $\omega=\alpha$.

The code for the linear approximation and its transpose at $X_{0}(\mu_{0})$:

```
α= ω;
JX0μ0 = Simplify@J[X0μ0, μ0];
JtX0μ0 = Simplify@Transpose@JX0μ0;
MatrixForm@JX0μ0
MatrixForm@JtX0μ0
Eigenvalues[JX0μ0]
```

The next step is to translate the equilibrium $X_{0}(\mu_{0})$ to the origin of coordinates:

```
bb = {0, 0};
F0[{x_, y_}, {α_, β_}] = Collect[Expand@F[X + X0μ0, μ0], {x, x^2, y, y^2, x y, x^2 y},Factor]
MatrixForm@F0[bb,μ]
```

Now, to  obtain the normal form of the Hopf bifurcation, we need the Taylor expansion of the third order for $F_{0}((x,y),(\alpha,\beta))$:

```
(*Rank 3 tensor*)
D2[{x_, y_}, {α_, β_}] = Simplify@D[F0[X, μ], {X, 2}]
D2X0μ0 = Simplify@D2[bb, μ0]
(*Rank 4 tensor*)
D3[{x_, y_}, {α_, β_}] = Simplify@D[F0[X, μ], {X, 3}]
D3X0μ0 = Simplify@D3[bb, μ0]
```

Multilinear forms:

```
(*Bilinear form*)
BB[{x_, y_}, {u_, v_}] = Collect[Expand[D2X0μ0.X.U], {u x, v y, v x, v y}, FullSimplify];
MatrixForm[BB[{x, y}, {u, v}]]
(*Trilinear form*)
CC[{x_, y_}, {u_, v_}, {r_, s_}] = Collect[Expand[D3X0μ0.X.U.R], {r u x, r u y, r v x, r v y, s u x, s v x, s u y, s v y}, FullSimplify]
MatrixForm[CC[{x, y}, {u, v}, {r, s}]]
```

We verify that the first three terms of the Taylor series expansion of $F_{0}((x,y),(\alpha,\beta))$ are correct:

```
A=JX0μ0; (*linear approximation*)
MatrixForm@FullSimplify[F0[X, μ] - (A.X + 1/2! BB[X, X] + 1/3! CC[X, X, X]) /. {x -> t x, y -> t y}]
(*{0,0}*)
```

Now, we compute the critical eigenvectors of $J((0,0),\mu_{0})$ and its transpose:

```
(*Eigenvectors of A=J[X0,μ0]*)
vp = ComplexExpand@Eigenvectors[A]
q = vp[[2]];
qc = vp[[1]];
MatrixForm@q
MatrixForm@qc
MatrixForm@Simplify[A.q - I ω q]
(*Eigenvectors of Transpose[A]*)
At=JtX0μ0;
vpt = ComplexExpand[Eigenvectors[At]]
(*Normalization constant*)
cn = ComplexExpand[Conjugate[vp[[1]] . vpt[[1]]]]
p = Expand@Simplify[vpt[[2]]/cn];
pc = ComplexExpand[Conjugate[p]];
MatrixForm@p
MatrixForm@pc
Simplify[At.p-I ω p]
```

We verify the normalization condition $\langle p,q\rangle=1$

```
Simplify@(p.q)
(*1*)
```

Finally, we compute the first Lyapunov coefficient:
$$
\begin{align}
l_1(0,\mu_{0})= &\frac{1}{2\omega_0} {\rm Re}\left[\langle p,C(q,q,\bar{q}) \rangle - 2 \langle p, B(q,A_0^{-1}B(q,\bar{q}))\rangle 
+\\\hspace{0.5cm} \langle p, B(\bar{q},(2i\omega_0 I_n-A_0)^{-1}B(q,q))\rangle \right]
\end{align}
$$

Before to calculate $l_1(0,\mu_{0})$, we clean $\alpha$

```
Clear[α]
ω0=α;
```

The code for the first Lyapunov coefficient:

```
Factor@ComplexExpand[Re[1/(2 ω) (p.CC[q, q, qc] - 2 (p.BB[q, Inverse[A].BB[q, qc]]) + p.BB[qc, Inverse[2 I ω*IdentityMatrix[2] - A].BB[q, q]])] /. ω -> ω0]
(*-((2 + α^2)/(2 α (1 + α^2)))*)
```

$$
\begin{align}
l_1(0,\mu_{0})=-\frac{\alpha^2+2}{2 \alpha \left(\alpha^2+1\right)}
\end{align}
$$
The first Lyapunov coefficient is clearly negative for all positive $\alpha$. Thus, the Hopf bifurcation is nondegenerate and always supercritical.

The above expression is the result that Kuznetsov arrives at on page 105 of his book (see [Elements of Applied Bifurcation Theory](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-3978-7)).

Limit cycle:

[image: Limit cycle]

For more details, see: [Andronov-Hopf bifurcation](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Andronov-Hopf_bifurcation).

Comment: Any recommendations on literature / material about this?

Comment: Elements of Applied Bifurcation Theory - Yuri A. Kuznetsov. Sorry, I hope my recommendation is useful after such a long time. XD

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid that you have calculated the stability incorrectly. Here is the Jacobian of your system:

```
a = 2; b = 1; c = 2.5; d = 1.2; k = 2.8;
jac[x_, y_] := {{D[a x*(1 - x/k) - b x*y, x], D[a x*(1 - x/k) - b x*y, y]}, 
               {D[-c y + d x*y, x], D[-c y + d x*y, y]}};
```

At the equilibrium, this is:

```
jacEq = jac[x, y] //. {x -> 2.08333, y -> 0.511905}
```

The eigenvalues of this are:

```
Re[Eigenvalues[jacEq]]
{-0.744047, -0.744047}
```

so the system is stable about this equilibrium.