# Routh-Hurwitz criterion not giving correct answer when done manually?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear, eigenvalues, stability

Consider the system:

\begin{align}
            \frac{dS}{dt} &= \nu N -\frac{\beta S I}{N} + \xi R - \nu S\\
            \frac{dE}{dt} &= \frac{\beta S I}{N}- \sigma E -\nu E  \\[2ex]
            \frac{dI}{dt} &= \sigma E -\gamma I -\nu I \\[2ex]
            \frac{dR}{dt} &= \gamma I -\xi R - \nu R
            \end{align}

The Jacobian is:
\begin{align}
J\left(S,E,I\right) = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
        -\frac{\beta I_2^*}{N}-B &-\xi &  -\frac{\beta S_2^*}{N}-\xi  \\[1ex] \frac{\beta I_2^*}{N} & -C & \frac{\beta S_2^*}{N}\\[1ex] 0 &  \sigma & -D
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
where $S_2^*=\frac{CDN}{\beta \sigma}$ $I_2^* = \frac{BN(-C D  +  \beta \sigma)}{\beta (C D + D \xi + \xi \sigma)}$

Where $B = \xi + \nu, \quad C = \sigma+\nu \quad \text{and } D = \gamma + \nu$.

The characteristic polynomial reads:

\begin{align*}
P\left(\lambda\right) &= \lambda ^3 + \left[B +C +D + \frac{B\left(\beta \sigma -CD \right)}{CD + \xi\left(D+\sigma\right)} \right]\lambda^2\\[2ex] & \quad+\left[BC + BD + \frac{BC\left(\beta \sigma -CD \right)}{CD + \xi\left(D+\sigma\right)} +\frac{BD\left(\beta \sigma -CD \right)}{CD + \xi\left(D+\sigma\right)}+\frac{B\xi \left(\beta \sigma -CD \right)}{CD + \xi\left(D+\sigma\right)} \right]\lambda\\[2ex] & \quad+\left[B\left(\beta \sigma -CD\right) \right]
\end{align*}

Using Chris K's EcoEvo package to test the stability we see:

```
Simplify[EcoStableQ[eq2[[2]]]]
```

outputs:

True when $CD<\beta \sigma$ and false when $CD>\beta \sigma$, which is as expected.

Now when I try to do it with brute force using the Routh-Hurwitz conditions:

\begin{align}
a_1 & > 0\\[1ex]
a_3 & > 0\\[1ex]
a_1 a_2 & > a_3
\end{align}
For our system:
\begin{align*}
a_1 & = B +C +D + \frac{B\left(\beta \sigma -CD \right)}{CD + \xi\left(D+\sigma\right)} \\[2.5ex]& = \frac{C^2 D + C D^2 + B D \xi + C D \xi + D^2 \xi + B \beta \sigma + B \xi \sigma + C \xi \sigma + D \xi \sigma}{CD + \xi\left(D+\sigma\right)} \\[3ex]
a_2 & = BC + BD + \frac{BC\left(\beta \sigma -CD \right)}{CD + \xi\left(D+\sigma\right)} +\frac{BD\left(\beta \sigma -CD \right)}{CD + \xi\left(D+\sigma\right)}+\frac{B\xi \left(\beta \sigma -CD \right)}{CD + \xi\left(D+\sigma\right)}  \\[2.5ex] & = \frac{B D^2 \xi + B C \beta \sigma + B D \beta \sigma + B C \xi \sigma + B D \xi \sigma + B \beta \xi \sigma}{CD + \xi\left(D+\sigma\right)}\\[3ex]
a_3 & =B\left(\beta \sigma -CD\right)
\end{align*}

Clearly $a_1>0$ and $a_3>0$ if $\frac{\beta \sigma}{CD} >1$ but why is the third condition failing when it should hold as we see from Chris's package?

We know a priori if $\frac{\beta \sigma}{CD} >1$ then the eigenvalue(s) must have negative real parts implying the equilibrium point is stable.

**EDIT**:

Here is the system is Mathematica(you will need to load the package in Mathematica first; `PacletInstall["EcoEvo", "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/cklausme/EcoEvo/master"]` and `` << EcoEvo` ``:

```
r := n - s - e - i;
SetModel[{Pop[
    pop] -> {Component[
      s] -> {Equation :> 
       B n - ξ e - ξ i - (β/n) s i  - B s}, 
    Component[e] -> {Equation :>  (β/n) s i - C e }, 
    Component[i] -> {Equation :> σ e - D i }}, 
  Parameters :> {β > 0, A > 0, ξ > 0, σ > 0, B > 0, 
    C > 0, D > 0}}]
eq2 = SolveEcoEq[]
```

**EDIT 2**:

The paper:

[image]

I believe the author has made a typo in equation (75) on the second matrix.

Their model is slightly different:

```
r := 1 - s - e - i;
SetModel[{Pop[
    pop] -> {Component[
      s] -> {Equation :> 
       A - \[Alpha] e - \[Alpha] i - \[Beta] s i  - B s}, 
    Component[e] -> {Equation :>  \[Beta] s i - C e }, 
    Component[i] -> {Equation :> \[Sigma] e - D i }}, 
  Parameters :> {\[Beta] > 0, A > 0, \[Xi] > 0, \[Sigma] > 0, B > 0, 
    C > 0, D > 0}}]
eq3 = SolveEcoEq[]
```

Their $S_2^*=\frac{CD}{\beta \sigma}$,  $I_2^* = \frac{-B C D  +  \beta \sigma A}{\beta (C D + D \alpha + \alpha \sigma)}$

By remarkable chance, they managed to show R-H criteria working as expected with their typo!

Comment: What happened to the fourth variable `R`? Should that not also be accounted for in the Jacobian?

Comment: We reduced the system since we have the equality $S+E+I+R=N$

Answer (score 12):

I can't say why your approach didn't work, but my [RouthHurwitzCriteria](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/ref/RouthHurwitzCriteria.nb) function uses a simplified test for 3x3 matrices due to Fuller (1968), which I first learned about from [Gandolfo (1997)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Economic_Dynamics/ZMwXi67nhHQC?hl=en&gbpv=0):

[image]

There are extensions to higher-order systems in [Murata (1977)](https://www.elsevier.com/books/mathematics-for-stability-and-optimization-of-economic-systems/murata/978-0-12-511250-5) that I thought about implementing, but never had the time.  Any matrix lovers out there want to help?

Fuller AT. 1968. Conditions for a matrix to have only characteristic roots with negative real parts. Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications 23: 71-98.

Comment: Thank you for the references. Since you have answered a few of my questions and hence, are well aware of these models, shouldn't the R-H conditions presented in my question hold $\textit{if}$ $\mathcal{R}_0>1$?

Comment: Higher-order you mean 4x4 matrix, 4D dynamic system? But that is not needed, no?

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Needed by OP? No. Needed by me? Not too much, but I wouldn't mind.

Comment: Are there real applications for 4x4 Hurwitz stable matrices? That is not 4 degree polinomials Hurwitz stability, Hurwitz matrix always has some zero elements...

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников It seems potentially useful for analytical results in the narrow range of cases where the resulting algebraic conditions are not too complicated. Otherwise you're probably stuck with numerical results, in which case calculating the eigenvalues isn't such a big deal. All of which is why I haven't bothered to implement it!

Answer (score 7):

Your approach didn't work because the last condition cannot be solved easily, that is, you need at least one parameter of degree one to solve without complexity. Then, Chris's routine does work perfectly.

However, it is possible to analyze stability if we think about the Hopf bifurcation, and we solve the following equation

$$\label{1}
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
 J_{11}+J_{22} & J_{23} & -J_{13} \\
 J_{32} & J_{11}+J_{33} & J_{12} \\
 -J_{31} & J_{21} & J_{22}+J_{33} \\
\end{array}
\right|=0,\tag 1
$$
for some parameter of your system. Firstly, if we consider $\beta=\displaystyle\frac{cd}{\sigma}$, we obtain the following three real eigenvalues:

$$
\lambda_{1}=-b,\hspace{0.1cm}\lambda_{2}=-c,\hspace{0.1cm}\lambda_{3}=-d.
$$
Secondly, as an example, for $\beta>\displaystyle\frac{cd}{\sigma}$ we set $d=\xi=1$, $c=1/100$, $\sigma=13$, $\beta=\displaystyle\frac{101}{1300}$ and solve $(\ref{1})$ for $b$.

Your linear approximation:

```
S2 = (c d n)/(β σ); I2 = (b n (β σ - c d))/(β (c d + d ξ + ξ σ));
J = {{-((β I2)/n) - b, -ξ, -((β S2)/n) - ξ}, {(β I2)/n, -c, (β I2)/n}, {0, σ, -d}};
M = {{J[[2, 2]] + J[[1, 1]], J[[2, 3]], -J[[1, 3]]}, {J[[3, 2]], 
J[[3, 3]] + J[[1, 1]], J[[1, 2]]}, {-J[[3, 1]], J[[2, 1]], J[[3, 3]] + J[[2, 2]]}};
```

The Hopf bifurcation values:

```
detM[{b_, c_, d_, β_, σ_, ξ_}] := Evaluate[Det[M]]
b1=Solve[Factor[detM[{b, 1/100, 1, 101/1300, 13, 1}]] == 0, b][[1, 1, 2]]
b2=Solve[Factor[detM[{b, 1/100, 1, 101/1300, 13, 1}]] == 0, b][[2, 1, 2]]
```

The transversality condition for $b_{1}$ and $b_{2}$:

```
Factor[-D[detM[{b, 1/100, 1, 101/1300, 13, 1}], b] /. b -> b1]
(*-(Sqrt[107236043973001]/14010000)*)
(*locally stable for b<b1*)
Factor[-D[detM[{b, 1/100, 1, 101/1300, 13, 1}], b] /. b -> b2]
(*(Sqrt[107236043973001]/14010000)*)
(*locally stable for b>b2*)
```

You can verify with the roots.

**Appendix**

Typo:

```
 J = {{-((β I2)/n) - b, -ξ, -((β S2)/n) - ξ}, {(β I2)/n, -c, (β I2)/n}, {0, σ, -d}};(*incorrect*)
 J = {{-((β I2)/n) - b, -ξ, -((β S2)/n) - ξ}, {(β I2)/n, -c, (β S2)/n}, {0, σ, -d}}; (*correct*)
```

Example: If we set $\beta=\displaystyle\frac{\beta_{0}+cd}{\sigma}$ ($\beta_{0}>0$), $d=\xi$ and $b=\sigma$, your equilibrium point is locally stable.

Your characteristic polynomial:

```
pol = a0 λ^3 + a1 λ^2 + a2 λ + a3;
```

where

```
a0 = 1;
a1 = c + ξ + σ + (β0 σ)/(ξ (c + ξ + σ));
a2 = (σ (c^2 ξ + ξ (2 β0 + ξ (ξ + σ)) +c (β0 + ξ (2 ξ + σ))))/(ξ (c + ξ + σ)):
a3 = -β0 σ + (σ (c + ξ + σ + (β0 σ)/(ξ (c + ξ + σ))) (c^2 ξ + ξ 
    (2 β0 + ξ (ξ + σ)) + c (β0 + ξ (2 ξ + σ))))/(ξ (c + ξ + σ))
H2 = a1 a2 - a3;
```

Checking stability:

```
Reduce[a1 > 0 && a2 > 0 && H2 > 0 && β0 > 0 && σ > 0 && ξ > 0 && c > 0]
(*σ > 0 && ξ > 0 && β0 > 0 && c > 0*)
```

Stability via Hopf bifurcation:

Example: If we set $\beta=\displaystyle\frac{\beta_{0}+cd}{\sigma}$ we can verify the stability as follows:

```
 pol = a0 λ^3 + a1 λ^2 + a2 λ + a3; (*characteristic polynomial*)
```

where

```
a0 = 1;
a1 = b + c + d + (b β0)/(c d + ξ (d + σ));
a2 = (b (c^2 d + d^2 ξ + β0 ξ + d (β0 + ξ σ) + c (d^2 + β0 + d ξ 
     + ξ σ)))/(c d + ξ (d + σ));
a3 = b β0;
H2 = a1 a2 - a3;
Collect[H2, b, FullSimplify]
(*(b^2 (c d + β0 + ξ (d + σ)) (c^2 d + d^2 ξ + β0 ξ + d (β0 + ξ σ) + c (β0 + d (d + ξ) + ξ σ)))/(c d + ξ (d + σ))^2 + b (-β0 + (c + d) (c + d + (β0 (c + d + ξ))/(c d + ξ (d + σ))))*)
```

Solve $H_{2}=0$ for $b$ and find the critical value of the Hopf bifurcation $b=b_{0}$. Then, analyze the stability with respect to $b_{0}$.

```
Factor[Reduce[a1 > 0 && a2 > 0 && H2 > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && ξ > 0 && σ > 0 && β0 > 0 && b > 0, b]]
(*Conditions "arbitrary values"*)
```

This is the strategy I followed. Check it out.

**Remark**

Symbolically, the Routh-Hurwitz test consists of solving inequalities that can be simple or very complicated. There is no loss of generality if you choose to solve the inequalities for some parameter. We only determine the conditions (inequalities) on the parameters to obtain the local stability of our equilibrium.

**Remark**

The following matrix:

$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{11}+a_{22} & a_{23} & -a_{13} \\
 a_{32} & a_{11}+a_{33} & a_{12} \\
 -a_{31} & a_{21} & a_{22}+a_{33} \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
corresponds to the bialternate matrix product $2 A \odot I_{3}$. You can use a bialternate matrix product to extend the stability criteria for higher dimensions of the phase space. For more details, see [Elements of Applied Bifurcation Theory - Yuri A. Kuznetsov](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-3978-7) (Appendix B).

**You can use [`BialternateSum`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BialternateSum/)**.

Comment: How did you get those eigenvalues?

Comment: Math Playing with equation (1) (Hopf bifurcation condition) and considering the assumptions on the parameters. For more details, see Elements of Applied Bifurcation Theory - Yuri A. Kuznetsov.

Comment: Math Arbitrary values imply to solve a nonlinear inequality, check that.

Comment: Oh, I see, I have a typo. Let me improve my post.

Comment: Through the Hopf bifurcation, the stability analysis is more general, I hope you understand that the change β = (β0+cd)/σ absorbs the inequality β> cd/σ.  Greetings!

Comment: I'm a little confused with notation since I have already defined $B, C$ and $D$ from the original system. I will edit my post.

Comment: Although your solution seems nice, it isn't the brute force method which is what I'm looking for. As I stated in my post, we know a priori that if $\frac{\beta \sigma}{C D} >1$ then we know that this equilibrium point $(S_2^*, I_2^*)$ is locally stable so using the R-H criteria manually should prove this but unfortunately it doesn't hold.. I will edit a paper that I was reading who has a similar model.

Comment: In your solution, you solved the equation for $b$, my question is; why? I forgot to define $b= \xi+\nu$, $c=\sigma+\nu$ and $d=\gamma+\nu$ in my original question. Greetings!

Comment: Because for $b$ the inequality is easier to solve, but you can try for other parameters that appear with a degree greater than two (the parameter you are interested in analyzing).

Comment: Ok this is understood. However, I still don't understand why we must fix numerical values to the parameters? Can one permutation of fixed numerical parameters lead to local stability of the equilibrium point in question and whilst another permutation leads to local instability? this is my confusion.. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Exactly, there are combinations of parameters that can lead to loss of equilibrium stability, as happens with the Hopf bifurcation. However, even at a Hopf bifurcation, there is a direction in which you can always guarantee local stability. See http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Andronov-Hopf_bifurcation

Comment: I mean, in the initial example you gave, with the contrived values, we saw local stability however, I want to show the equilibrium point is locally stable for arbitrary values of parameters. So the conditions in R-H shows stability for arbitrary values if they hold. I'm sorry if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: The last example is for arbitrary values of the parameters, since I do not assign numeric values to the parameters.

Comment: Aha, got it! many thanks Sir. Please double check the computations since I didn't get them, maybe you have some typo's.

Comment: Can you expand on "Solve $H_2=0$ for $b$ and find the critical value of the Hopf bifurcation $b=b_0$. Then, analyze the stability with respect to $b_0$." because i don't seem to get the any answers. Strange.

Comment: Shouldn't you have solved matrix $M$ and not $J$?

Comment: @E. Chan-López:  Why didn’t you check all 3 conditions of Hopf bifurcation theorem(non-hyperbolicity, transversality, genericity)?

Comment: You can do it. See the following post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118226/plotting-limit-cycle/159731#159731

Comment: The matrix elements of $M$ are constructed with the matrix elements of $J$.

Comment: @Math You can use the following function: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BialternateSum/

Comment: Can you add how to use your new FunctionRepository function?

Comment: Валерий, you can download the function repository notebook, and there I put some examples of its use in local stability and Hopf bifurcation.

Answer (score 2):

Conditions 1 and 2 are trivially satisfied. Now we deal with the 3rd condition. We simplify here by multiplication of both sides with denominator and take the RHS to the LHS yielding:

```
B C^3 D^3 + 3 B C^2 D^3 \[Xi] + B C D^4 \[Xi] + B^2 D^3 \[Xi]^2 + 
 2 B C D^3 \[Xi]^2 + B D^4 \[Xi]^2 + B C^3 D \[Beta] \[Sigma] + 
 B C^2 D^2 \[Beta] \[Sigma] + B C D^3 \[Beta] \[Sigma] + 
 B C^3 D \[Xi] \[Sigma] + 4 B C^2 D^2 \[Xi] \[Sigma] + 
 B C D^3 \[Xi] \[Sigma] + B^2 C D \[Beta] \[Xi] \[Sigma] + 
 2 B C^2 D \[Beta] \[Xi] \[Sigma] + 2 B^2 D^2 \[Beta] \[Xi] \[Sigma] +
  B C D^2 \[Beta] \[Xi] \[Sigma] + B D^3 \[Beta] \[Xi] \[Sigma] + 
 B^2 C D \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + B C^2 D \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + 
 2 B^2 D^2 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + 5 B C D^2 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + 
 2 B D^3 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + B^2 D \[Beta] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + 
 B C D \[Beta] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + B^2 C \[Beta]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 B^2 D \[Beta]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 2 B^2 C \[Beta] \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + 
 B C^2 \[Beta] \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + 2 B^2 D \[Beta] \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + 
 B D^2 \[Beta] \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + B^2 \[Beta]^2 \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + 
 B^2 C \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + B C^2 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 B^2 D \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 3 B C D \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 B D^2 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + B^2 \[Beta] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 B C \[Beta] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 - B D \[Beta] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 - 
 B \[Beta] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^3 >0
```

Since we have $B= \xi +\nu$, $C=\sigma+\nu$ and $D=\gamma+\nu$, we input this into the above expression, we obtain:

```
\[Gamma]^3 \[Nu]^4 + 3 \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu]^5 + 
 3 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^6 + \[Nu]^7 + \[Gamma]^4 \[Nu]^2 \[Xi] + 
 8 \[Gamma]^3 \[Nu]^3 \[Xi] + 18 \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu]^4 \[Xi] + 
 16 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^5 \[Xi] + 5 \[Nu]^6 \[Xi] + 
 2 \[Gamma]^4 \[Nu] \[Xi]^2 + 14 \[Gamma]^3 \[Nu]^2 \[Xi]^2 + 
 30 \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu]^3 \[Xi]^2 + 26 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^4 \[Xi]^2 + 
 8 \[Nu]^5 \[Xi]^2 + \[Gamma]^4 \[Xi]^3 + 
 8 \[Gamma]^3 \[Nu] \[Xi]^3 + 18 \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu]^2 \[Xi]^3 + 
 16 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^3 \[Xi]^3 + 
 5 \[Nu]^4 \[Xi]^3 + \[Gamma]^3 \[Xi]^4 + 
 3 \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu] \[Xi]^4 + 
 3 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^2 \[Xi]^4 + \[Nu]^3 \[Xi]^4 + \[Beta] \[Gamma]^3 \
\[Nu]^2 \[Sigma] + 4 \[Beta] \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu]^3 \[Sigma] + 
 3 \[Gamma]^3 \[Nu]^3 \[Sigma] + 
 6 \[Beta] \[Gamma] \[Nu]^4 \[Sigma] + 
 9 \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu]^4 \[Sigma] + 3 \[Beta] \[Nu]^5 \[Sigma] + 
 9 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^5 \[Sigma] + 3 \[Nu]^6 \[Sigma] + 
 2 \[Beta] \[Gamma]^3 \[Nu] \[Xi] \[Sigma] + \[Gamma]^4 \[Nu] \[Xi] \
\[Sigma] + 10 \[Beta] \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu]^2 \[Xi] \[Sigma] + 
 14 \[Gamma]^3 \[Nu]^2 \[Xi] \[Sigma] + 
 18 \[Beta] \[Gamma] \[Nu]^3 \[Xi] \[Sigma] + 
 40 \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu]^3 \[Xi] \[Sigma] + 
 10 \[Beta] \[Nu]^4 \[Xi] \[Sigma] + 
 43 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^4 \[Xi] \[Sigma] + 
 16 \[Nu]^5 \[Xi] \[Sigma] + \[Beta] \[Gamma]^3 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + \
\[Gamma]^4 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + 
 8 \[Beta] \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + 
 15 \[Gamma]^3 \[Nu] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + 
 19 \[Beta] \[Gamma] \[Nu]^2 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + 
 50 \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu]^2 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + 
 12 \[Beta] \[Nu]^3 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + 
 62 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^3 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + 26 \[Nu]^4 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma] + 
 2 \[Beta] \[Gamma]^2 \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma] + 
 4 \[Gamma]^3 \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma] + 
 8 \[Beta] \[Gamma] \[Nu] \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma] + 
 21 \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu] \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma] + 
 6 \[Beta] \[Nu]^2 \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma] + 
 33 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^2 \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma] + 
 16 \[Nu]^3 \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma] + \[Beta] \[Gamma] \[Xi]^4 \[Sigma] + 
 2 \[Gamma]^2 \[Xi]^4 \[Sigma] + \[Beta] \[Nu] \[Xi]^4 \[Sigma] + 
 5 \[Gamma] \[Nu] \[Xi]^4 \[Sigma] + 
 3 \[Nu]^2 \[Xi]^4 \[Sigma] + \[Beta] \[Gamma]^3 \[Nu] \[Sigma]^2 + \
\[Beta]^2 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 5 \[Beta] \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 3 \[Gamma]^3 \[Nu]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 2 \[Beta]^2 \[Nu]^3 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 10 \[Beta] \[Gamma] \[Nu]^3 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 9 \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu]^3 \[Sigma]^2 + 6 \[Beta] \[Nu]^4 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 9 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^4 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 3 \[Nu]^5 \[Sigma]^2 + \[Beta] \[Gamma]^3 \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + 
 2 \[Beta]^2 \[Gamma] \[Nu] \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + 
 7 \[Beta] \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu] \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + 
 7 \[Gamma]^3 \[Nu] \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + 
 5 \[Beta]^2 \[Nu]^2 \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + 
 21 \[Beta] \[Gamma] \[Nu]^2 \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + 
 29 \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu]^2 \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + 
 18 \[Beta] \[Nu]^3 \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + 
 40 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^3 \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + 
 18 \[Nu]^4 \[Xi] \[Sigma]^2 + \[Beta]^2 \[Gamma] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 \
+ 2 \[Beta] \[Gamma]^2 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 4 \[Gamma]^3 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 4 \[Beta]^2 \[Nu] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 14 \[Beta] \[Gamma] \[Nu] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 26 \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 19 \[Beta] \[Nu]^2 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 50 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^2 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 30 \[Nu]^3 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^2 + \[Beta]^2 \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 3 \[Beta] \[Gamma] \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 6 \[Gamma]^2 \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 8 \[Beta] \[Nu] \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 21 \[Gamma] \[Nu] \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 18 \[Nu]^2 \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma]^2 + \[Beta] \[Xi]^4 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 2 \[Gamma] \[Xi]^4 \[Sigma]^2 + 
 3 \[Nu] \[Xi]^4 \[Sigma]^2 + \[Beta] \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu] \[Sigma]^3 + \
\[Gamma]^3 \[Nu] \[Sigma]^3 + \[Beta]^2 \[Nu]^2 \[Sigma]^3 + 
 5 \[Beta] \[Gamma] \[Nu]^2 \[Sigma]^3 + 
 3 \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu]^2 \[Sigma]^3 + 4 \[Beta] \[Nu]^3 \[Sigma]^3 + 
 3 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^3 \[Sigma]^3 + \[Nu]^4 \[Sigma]^3 + \[Beta] \
\[Gamma]^2 \[Xi] \[Sigma]^3 + \[Gamma]^3 \[Xi] \[Sigma]^3 + 
 2 \[Beta]^2 \[Nu] \[Xi] \[Sigma]^3 + 
 7 \[Beta] \[Gamma] \[Nu] \[Xi] \[Sigma]^3 + 
 7 \[Gamma]^2 \[Nu] \[Xi] \[Sigma]^3 + 
 10 \[Beta] \[Nu]^2 \[Xi] \[Sigma]^3 + 
 14 \[Gamma] \[Nu]^2 \[Xi] \[Sigma]^3 + 
 8 \[Nu]^3 \[Xi] \[Sigma]^3 + \[Beta]^2 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^3 + 
 2 \[Beta] \[Gamma] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^3 + 
 4 \[Gamma]^2 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^3 + 
 8 \[Beta] \[Nu] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^3 + 
 15 \[Gamma] \[Nu] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^3 + 
 14 \[Nu]^2 \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^3 + 2 \[Beta] \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma]^3 + 
 4 \[Gamma] \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma]^3 + 
 8 \[Nu] \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma]^3 + \[Xi]^4 \[Sigma]^3 + \[Beta] \[Gamma] \
\[Nu] \[Sigma]^4 + \[Beta] \[Nu]^2 \[Sigma]^4 + \[Beta] \[Gamma] \
\[Xi] \[Sigma]^4 + 
 2 \[Beta] \[Nu] \[Xi] \[Sigma]^4 + \[Gamma] \[Nu] \[Xi] \[Sigma]^4 + \
\[Nu]^2 \[Xi] \[Sigma]^4 + \[Beta] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^4 + \[Gamma] \
\[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^4 + 2 \[Nu] \[Xi]^2 \[Sigma]^4 + \[Xi]^3 \[Sigma]^4 >0
```

Since all entries are positive on the left hand side, the third condition is satisfied.

Hence by the Routh-Hurwitz condition, all eigenvalues have negative real parts and we conclude that the endemic equilibrium is locally stable.